# lpSolve running for extended period of time without finishing

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am trying to optimize a transportation problem in R using `lpSolve::lp.transport`. My code is as follows:

```
library(lpSolve)

cost <- matrix(rep(100, 34968), nrow = 372)
row.signs <- rep("<=", 372)
row.RHS <- c(t(vehicleGVWR2[,2]))
col.signs <- rep(">=", 94)
col.RHS <- c(t(branchGVWR[, 2]))

lptrans <- lp.transport(cost, "min", row.signs, row.RHS, col.signs, col.RHS)
```

The cost matrix is "100" at every value because the cost of assignment is considered to be negligible/the same for each combination.

The cost matrix is 372x94. Is this too many variables for the function to handle? Or will the code eventually complete running?

Comment: How long exactly is an "extended period of time"?

Comment: LpSolve is not the fastest LP solver. However, a transportation problem is a network problem, so it may be faster to solve with a network solver.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the branchGVWR and branchGVWR2 vectors so we can test.  However without those, since all of your cost coefficients are exactly equal, the problem solution is probably massively degenerate.  So the solver is moving from solution to solution where the solutions are always equal.  You could try adding a random epsilon value to each cost coefficient:

```
cost <- matrix(rep(100,34968),nrow = 372)
cost <- abs(rnorm(34968)) + cost
```

and see if that fixes the timeout problem.